# Format number while typing

Tags: javascript, user-interface, antd

I am using antd `InputNumber` component as input for amount value.

```
                            <InputNumber
                                controls={false}
                                placeholder="0"
                                readOnly={isLoadingCurrencies}
                                onChange={send.onAmountChangeDebounced}
                                parser={v => {
                                    console.log(v)
                                    return `${v}`.replace(',', '.')
                                }}
                                formatter={v => `${v}`.replace(',', '.')}
                            />
```

while this kinda works (meaning it does replace comma with dot but only after input if blurred).
What I need is comma to be replaced with immediately after user presses ",". User should not be able to type see this character while still being able to enter it(will be replaced with dot)
I don't think API has something for this, so I need some kind of workaround.

I also have tried setting parsed value to form using `form.setFieldValue(...)` it did not help

Answer (score -1):

Here is my attempt as per your *challenge*:

You'll need to implement a custom handler for the input event because the `onChange` event in Ant Design's InputNumber is not suitable as it triggers after the input loses focus (on blur), not immediately after the input changes.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { InputNumber } from 'antd';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if (e.key === ',') {
            e.preventDefault();
            const newValue = value + '.';
            setValue(newValue);
        }
    };

    const handleChange = (newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <InputNumber
            controls={false}
            placeholder="0"
            readOnly={isLoadingCurrencies}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
            formatter={v => `${v}`.replace(',', '.')}
        />
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

1. `handleKeyPress` checks for comma key presses and replaces them with dots
2. `handleChange` updates the state with the new value whenever the input changes
3. The value prop of `InputNumber` is controlled by a state variable, ensuring that the displayed value is always in sync with the component's state

Answer (score -3):

I don't think it's possible at all.
If API of the component does not specify this behaviour maybe it is designed to be unavailable. Besides that input number uses rc-input-number under the hood, meaning you don't have control over it

Comment: maybe you are right

Comment: Hey Sheldon, you are getting voted down bcs yours is an opinion rather than an answer. Don't worry we've all been there. Try to avoid opinion based answers and prefer questions where you have a testable solution. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: @Jacob I challenge you to try, I have spend 2 days messing with API of the component, no result

Comment: @Jacob that is the solution everyone could come up with. The input is used inside a form, this is when problems start to occur. (I mean when we dont have control over the state of the input)

Comment: @howardwolowitz `antd` doesn't provide anything built-in for handling input validation in real-time but your question already mentions that: "I don't think API has something for this, so I need some kind of workaround."